# How do I display start / end states in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with date and status fields. I would like to aggregate the data to show start and stop times in order to make a horizontal time period chart. Image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuWuq.jpg.

I would like to have a "time allowance" that says "If the time is greater than X minutes, consider this a new time period. Here is the raw data:

```
DateTime                |        Status      |
12:01                       Online
12:02                       Online
12:04 (Notice Skip)         Online
12:07                       Online
12:08                       Offline
12:09                       Offline 
12:10                       Offline
12:11                       Offline
12:12                       Offline
1:45 (Big Skip)             Offline
1:46                        Offline
1:47                        Offline
1:48                        Offline
```

The final results should look like this. Notice the difference in a small skip of 2 minutes instead of 1, and the big skip > 1 hour, that either causes a new time period or not.

```
Start       |       End         |   Status
12:01               12:08           Online
12:08               12:12           Offline
1:45                1:48            Offline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query could help([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c117720ebb757e9dc30b7536245d4131)). This [article](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/09/t-sql-queries/special-islands) could be also useful:

```
select status, min(dt) s, max(dt) e 
from(
   select *, sum(dtDif) over (partition by status order by dt ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)  grp
   from(
      select *, case when EXTRACT(Minute FROM dt-prevdt) < 5 /*set your own value*/ then 0 else 1 end dtDif from(
         select *, lag (dt,1, dt) over (order by dt) prevdt
         from cte
        )q      
   )q1
)q2
group by status, grp
```

Comment: This works great, thank you for taking the time to write this out.